# make a json format with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i want to use a treeView in my angularjs, the data recieved from the server is:

```
[
    {
        "vehiculeid": 1,
        "name": "ggg",
        "id": 1,
        "group": "TGV"
    },
    {
        "vehiculeid": 5,
        "name": "eee",
        "id": 5,
        "group": "TGV"
    },
    {
        "vehiculeid": 6,
        "name": "tru123",
        "id": 8,
        "group": "TGV"
    },
    {
        "vehiculeid": 2,
        "name": "aqs",
        "id": 3,
        "group": "TCF"
    }
```

]
How can i make the data like the folowing data so that i can use it in treeView Component, this is that format which i want to got:

```
 treedata_avm = [{
    group: 'TGV',
    children: [{
        name: 'ggg',
        data: {
            vehiculeid: 1
        }
    }, {
        name: 'eee',
        data: {
            vehiculeid: 5
        }
    }, {
        name: 'tru123',
        data: {
            vehiculeid: 6
        }
    }]
},{
 group: 'TCF',
    children: [{
        name: 'aqs',
        data: {
            vehiculeid: 2
        }
    }]

    }]
```

How i can do that with javascript or angularjs to get this format?

P.S:
the data recieved from the server is dynamic.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. the objective here is to help you fix **your code** that isn't working as expected  after you have done exhaustive research to figure out how it can  be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```js
var test = [
    {
        "vehiculeid": 1,
        "name": "ggg",
        "id": 1,
        "group": "TGV"
    },
    {
        "vehiculeid": 5,
        "name": "eee",
        "id": 5,
        "group": "TGV"
    },
    {
        "vehiculeid": 6,
        "name": "tru123",
        "id": 8,
        "group": "TGV"
    },
    {
        "vehiculeid": 2,
        "name": "aqs",
        "id": 3,
        "group": "TCF"
    }
];
var test2 = {};
for(var i in test) {
  if(typeof test2[test[i]['group']] === 'undefined') {
    test2[test[i]['group']] = [];
  }
  test2[test[i]['group']].push({name: test[i]['name'], data: {vehiculeid: test[i]['vehiculeid']}})
}
var treedata_avm = [];
for(var j in test2) {
  var final = {};
  final['group'] = j;
  final['children'] = test2[j];
  treedata_avm.push(final)
}
console.log(treedata_avm)
```

Comment: look at your own logged result... it is empty arrays

Comment: I'm not sure why its logging empty arrays, it works in my browser's console. The code works, not sure why it doesn't in the snippet. Copy paste it in the browser to test

Comment: why i got this:[Array(0), Array(0)]

Comment: Check the snippet again. As @Jonasw pointed out, "final must be an object". Check the code now

Comment: Also note that *"Here's the code"* simply goes against the whole concept of this site. It is not intended to be a free code writing service

Comment: thanks man it works..when i need something i will get u back here..thanks a lot